# OS X PDF: Get Font Information

Tags: macos, pdf, fonts

Is there a simple way to get font information for a PDF file on Mac OSX? I should have thought that the Preview App would include this, but I can’t find it anywhere?

Failing that, is there another (cheap or free) application which will do this?

I definitely do *not* want to rely on something like Acrobat for this simple task.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of what you mention by far. It is however off-topic as it's not related to programming at all, but rather to general software and hardware knowledge. Superuser (for example) would be a better platform to ask this.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche You’re right — wrong forum.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sure, use `pdffonts` as follows:

```
pdffonts ~/Desktop/GNU\ Parallel.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DMBULJ+Sentinel-Light                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    266  0
DMBULJ+Sentinel-Semibold             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes yes    268  0
DMBULJ+Sentinel-LightItalic          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes yes    270  0
DMBULJ+Whitney-Light                 Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes yes    272  0
DMBULJ+OCRF-Light                    Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes yes    274  0
DMBULJ+Whitney-Medium                Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes yes    276  0
DMBULJ+Sentinel-BoldItalic           Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes yes     22  0
```

Or, another example:

```
pdffonts ~/Desktop/Applescript\ Commands\ Reference.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
MNFADS+Courier                       TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      12  0
GCBDOX+.HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no       8  0
BVTFLM+LucidaGrande                  TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      10  0
JBWSLS+LucidaGrande-Bold             TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      11  0
XGRGCO+LucidaGrande                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     60  0
LEFUMS+Courier-Bold                  TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      86  0
```

`pdffonts` is part of the `poppler` package which is easiest to install via `homebrew`. Basically, you go to [the homebrew website](http://brew.sh) and copy and paste the one-line installation script. At that point, you will have a proper package manager for OS X.

Then you can install `pdffonts` using:

```
brew install poppler
```

If you get any problems, call the good doctor with

```
brew doctor
```

Answer (score -3):

Adobe (Acrobat) Reader does provide the complete document information, as Acrobat; and it is free.

Comment: You know, I did say: “I definitely do not want to rely on something like Acrobat for this simple task.”